# When should namespaces and separate compilation be used? (Can separate compilation be used outside of classes?)

Tags: c++, function, class, compilation, namespaces

Regarding namespaces, I do not see why they should not always be used? For every header (.hpp) file and every source (.cpp) file, it seems like good practice to declare everything inside a namespace. Is there a circumstance when you would not want to declare something inside a namespace in a separate file? Additionally, can separate compilation be used for functions and not classes? I am currently experimenting with developing a game using openGL and there are a few separate classes that use the same function which is currently written in main.cpp. Would it make sense to declare these functions in a namespace in a separate .hpp file and implement them in a corresponding .cpp file even though they are not part of a class?

It would look something like this:

```
// foo.hpp
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

namespace Functions
{
    int function1(int x, int y, int z);
    void function2(char* ex);
    float function3(float a, float b, int c, int d);
}
#endif

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

int Functions::function1(int x, int y, int z)
{
    // some code
}

void Functions::function2(char* ex)
{
    // some code
}

float Functions::function3(float a, float b, int c, int d)
{
    // some code
}
```

EDIT:
Regarding comments and answers explaining to simply implement it in the class or not to replace classes with namespaces. To clarify, I should have noted that not all these classes inherit from a common ancestor, therefore I am trying to circumvent rewriting the function multiple times. I am not trying to entirely substitute a traditional class with a namespace. It was mentioned that a static class can accomplish this as well. So I guess I am sort of substituting a static class with a namespace. Therefore, my question at this point becomes why is this a bad thing? Why use a static class over a namespace for publicly used functions? They would essentially be used the same if I am not mistaken:

```
// foo.hpp using class
class Functions
{
public:
    static int function1(int x, int y, int z);
};

// foo.hpp using namespace
namespace Functions
{
    int function1(int x, int y, int z);
}

// foo.cpp
int Functions::function1(int x, int y, int z)  // prepend static for use with class
{
    // implementation
}

// someOtherFile.cpp
    // some code
    int value = Functions::function1(1,2,3); // same use
    // more code
```

Comment: Why namespace? Why not put them into a class? You probably want a static class.

Comment: @user34660 Because this is what namespaces were invented for.

Comment: And it is what classes are invented for. The question is highly general. If the functions are related such that they are part of an object then a class should be used.

Comment: @user34660 - there is no such thing as a "static class" in C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker conceptually a static class is one that cannot be instantiated and contains only static members, which can certainly be done in C++

Comment: @user34660 to clarify, I mentioned that the function would be used with a few separate classes. I should have noted that not all these classes inherit from a common ancestor, therefore I am trying to circumvent rewriting the function multiple times. I do see your point about static classes, but then what is the purpose of namespaces at all?

Comment: @Erix By whose definition? It isn't a standard C++ concept.

Comment: @user34660 No, if it can be done with a namespace then there is absolutely no reason to do it with a class. It would be the wrong abstraction to use.

Comment: @Pete Becker, yes, I am sorry; I am confusing C++ and C#.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you are free to use the [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) as you'd like, and you could use a different namespace for every source file.  However, I think this might be an overkill and somewhat redundant with the compilation units themselves.

The goal of namespaces is to avoid name collisions in larger projects.  It's a way to group items that logically belong together beyond individual classes.  Typically, you could use it for libraries (including [versioning](http://i1.dk/misc/c++versioning.html) of libraries, as explained in Stroustrup's book). Or to introduce some kind of modularity (whether horizontal by layer, or vertical by functional module).

Another use is the anonymous namespaces that allow within a cpp, to keep objects private and [inaccessible from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385015/3723423) (whether nested or not).

I think (but that's a personal viewpoint), that namespaces should not be used as substitute for classes, for example to emulate the java practices of having a compilation unit by class.  It should rather be viewed as a way to packaging things.

**EDIT:** Additional thoughts : If you want just to "*circumvent rewriting the function multiple times*", and if the functions should in principle rather be some member functions, you could consider:

- If there's a common ancestor,  make the functions member of the common ancestor.
- If there's not a common ancestor, either use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or put these functions in a [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) class
- If you intend to have several versions of your functions, and have a static or dynamic configuration on which set of function to use, put each set in a different class and use [strategy design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html)

On the other hand, if your functions are from their logic class independent, you could very well put them in a namespace.  My point was mainly against using namespaces as substitute for classes (i.e. putting some functions in a class that doesn't really correspond to some kind of abstraction) and afainst creating a different namespace for each compilation unit.

Comment: I think I was thinking the same thing (especially "larger projects" and "beyond individual classes") but I don't have enough experience to defend myself from criticism.

Comment: Looking at the question's edit, I couldn't still see the intent.  So it's difficult to go beyond general rule of thumbs advice.  I've nevertheless added a section to show cases where the functios should better be in some  class.